# Collection is not defined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi i'm new to MongoDB and I'm having trouble with some of the commands that i'm pretty sure should be working.

right now the collection is unfortunately named "fea5dc60-b898-11e4-ac68-a5f571ea05d9".  so i obviously would like to rename it.  but no matter what command I use, it keeps saying "b898 is not defined".  i have a feeling because the dashes in the name is causing confusion.

I've tried all of these and i keep getting that error.  I know the commands work because I installed MongoVUE which shows what commands it's using..and i straight copied and pasted that command into the console directly:

```
db.fea5dc60-b898-11e4-ac68-a5f571ea05d9.renameCollection("NAME")
db.fea5dc60-b898-11e4-ac68-a5f571ea05d9.find()
db.fea5dc60-b898-11e4-ac68-a5f571ea05d9.find().limit(100)
```

any help? i really would like to rename this collection!

EDIT (a sample of what's going on):

```
> show dbs
admin          (empty)
haymon_boxing  0.078GB
local          0.078GB
> use haymon_boxing
switched to db haymon_boxing
> show collections
fea5dc60-b898-11e4-ac68-a5f571ea05d9
system.indexes
> db.fea5dc60-b898-11e4-ac68-a5f571ea05d9.find().limit(100)
2015-03-02T13:29:31.818-0800 ReferenceError: b898 is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MongoDB, collections are not supposed to include certain characters like, for example, a hyphen "-" or a slash "/". The manual has this to say on the matter:

> Collection names should begin with letters or an underscore and may
>   include numbers; $ is reserved. Collections can be organized in
>   namespaces; these are named groups of collections defined using a dot
>   notation.

Otherwise wrap your collection in `[]` and make sure to remove any `.` after db...

Comment: unfortunately it was a collection that was given to me from one of the companies we're working with, so I had no choice in the matter.  thank you for your input though!

Comment: for those reading.. i'd like to point out that the "." after "db" is taken away and you must put it in double quotes.. like my answer below

Comment: You are correct, I didn't put that in but the true answer is the bracket's. I updated the answer though to include this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

this works

```
db["fea5dc60-b898-11e4-ac68-a5f571ea05d9"].find()
```

Comment: I found this more useful than the accepted answer as it has a clear example of what I was looking for. Although reading the two answers together gave me a better understanding.